# Text from Contribution page runs into my blog previews?

Tags: wordpress, civimember, contribution-page

Uh... It's totally possible that this question has been answered already, but I couldn't even really figure out what my search term would be to find it...

I'm working with a new Wordpress install (my first CiviCRM experience!) and have set up two contribution pages - one for any type of financial contribution, and one that is specifically a Membership sign-up. For each of them, there's the most basic text in advance (first, the automated, CiviCRM-provided "Welcome Ashley Morton. (Not Ashley Morton, or want to do this for a different person?)", then there's what I wrote. Just "Hi there! Thanks so much for your contribution!" (for the moment, at least.) That much is good, and it appears to be working properly.

Then, on the right-hand side of our page, we have a widget that previews the most recent two blog posts from the organization. Shows the title (clickable link), and then the first couple of sentences.

However, the contribution text, beginning with "Welcome Ashley..." has now replaced all of the blog-post preview text for every blog post!

It's so weird! Anyone heard of / seen this before? Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you say what widget you are using in the RH sidebar?  Is it the WP Recent Posts widget or is it another?  The first mentioned should, I think, only produce the title of each post.